# Android simple Interest Calculator

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm starter programmer on Android environment. And I need your help.

Here is the what I'm trying to do

[image]

---

```
package com.codeherenow.sicalculator;

import com.codeherenow.sicalculator.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SICalculatorActivity extends Activity {


    private TextView PA;
    private TextView Interest_Rate;
    private TextView Years;
    private EditText PA_bar;
    private EditText IR_bar;
    private SeekBar  year_bar;
    private Button   calculate;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sicalculator);

        PA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.PA);
        Interest_Rate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Interest_Rate);
        Years= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Years);
        PA_bar= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PA_bar);
        IR_bar= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.IR_bar);
        year_bar=(SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.year_bar);
        calculate=(Button) findViewById(R.id.calculate);

        calculate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v){


            }
        }


    }

}
```

My xml:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".SICalculatorActivity" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Years"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/IR_bar"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="2 Year(s)"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/year_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Years"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Years"
            android:layout_marginTop="21dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/calculate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/year_bar"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/year_bar"
            android:text="Calculate" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/IR_bar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/Years"
            android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Interest_Rate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/IR_bar"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/IR_bar"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:text="Interest Rate"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/PA"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/PA_bar"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:text="Principal Amount"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/PA_bar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Interest_rate"
            android:layout_below="@+id/PA"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

---

Actually , I need help for not xml part. I need help for java coding part. Even if i'm trying to use onclicklistener , compiler always show error on coding page? Could someone help me?

Comment: Add the error u get in the question. Also a better idea is as soon as user moves the seekbar the interest gets calculated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntactical error in your code. You are missing the closing parentheses and semi-colon.

```
calculate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v){


    }
}); //<--- Change is here.
```

Comment: Make your view variables `final` so they are visible within the `OnClickListener` and do your calculations.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {
 TextView PA;
 TextView Interest_Rate;
 TextView Years;
 EditText PA_bar;
 EditText IR_bar;
 EditText  year_bar;
 Button   calculate;
 TextView t1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    PA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.PA);
    Interest_Rate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Interest_Rate);
    Years = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Years);
    PA_bar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PA_bar);
    IR_bar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.IR_bar);
    year_bar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.year_bar);
    calculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculate);
    t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t1);

    calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int num1 = Integer.parseInt(PA_bar.getText().toString());
            int num2 = Integer.parseInt(IR_bar.getText().toString());
            int num = Integer.parseInt(year_bar.getText().toString());

            int si = (num1 * num2 * num) / 100;
            t1.setText(Integer.toString(si));
        }
    });
}};
```